# orderby Created is not working in SharePoint rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to orderby Created date in SharePoint Rest api

Below is the url that I use

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('style%20library/Gallery')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

I get the below error message

> -1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException  Field or property "Created" does not
>   exist.  Field or property
>   "Created" does not exist. 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is "Created" does not exist if you are playing with Files. You should use "*TimeCreated*" as a creation date in your query.

This is my query and it is working fine in my case:

```
_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('PSD')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields&$orderby=TimeCreated%20desc
```